# Why hwclock and date display different results and how to correct it

Tags: linux

In my Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine date is shown incorrectly. When I try to run hwclock and date commands from the terminal they display different results:

```
sudo hwclock
Thursday 14 August 2014 04:38:09 PM IST  -0.766043 seconds

date
Thu Aug 14 11:08:30 IST 2014
```

Here hwclock time is right, but date is wrong. How can I correct it.

Thanks

Comment: This is more suited on http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com. It might be a timezone issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like your hardware clock is set to local time. Run this:

```
hwclock --localtime --hctosys
```

See `hwclock --help` for more info.

You should configure your boot-time settings so that this would be the default action when restoring your system time from the hardware clock. Check the documentation of your distro.